# Reading from a file, only reads text untill it gets to empty space

Tags: c++, file, dev-c++

I managed to successfully read the text in a file but it only reads until it hits an empty space, for example the text: "Hi, this is a test", cout's as: "Hi,".

Removing the "," made no difference.

I think I need to add something similar to "`inFil.ignore(1000,'\n');`" to the following bit of code:

```
inFil>>text;
inFil.ignore(1000,'\n');
cout<<"The file cointains the following: "<<text<<endl;
```

I would prefer not to change to `getline(inFil, variabel);` because that would force me to redo a program that is essentially working.

Thank you for any help, this seems like a very small and easily fixed problem but I cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: It's good to refactor the program, if it's behavior needs to change.  Write a test around the reading part, and go for `readline`.  Once you have the test, you can start changing the program and feel safe about it.

Comment: "_force me to redo a program that is essentially working._" If the program reads "Hi," and you would want it to read "Hi, this is a test", how is the program "_essentially working_"?

Comment: I really don't see why the switch to getline() would be an atrocity for you. It changes nothing in the code, except it's exactly the small and easy fix you're looking for. Way more elegant than messing with the ignore(). Meh, you'd like to get a line, so why don't you use getline? And yeah, "essentially working", terrific.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
if(!file) throw std::exception("Could not open file.txt for reading!");
std::string line;
//read until the first \n is found, essentially reading line by line unti file ends
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
  //do something line by line
  std::cout << "Line : " << line << "\n";
}
```

This will help you read the file. I don't know what you are trying to achieve since your code is not complete but the above code is commonly used to read files in c++.

Comment: No need for assigning `""` to `line`, as it's constructed empty by default, anyway. Change it and you got a +1 more. And a little ammendment about `line` not containing the newline character at the end might be helpful (though that might be seen in the example already).

Comment: @ChristianRau Habit of initializing I guess :)

Comment: Please don't stream `std::endl` in a loop. It's quite wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

You've been using formatted extraction to extract a single string, once: this means a single word.

If you want a string containing the entire file contents:

```
std::fstream fs("/path/to/file");
std::string all_of_the_file(
   (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream)),
   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

Comment: +1 really nice C++ solution. I think few people know about the streambuf iterators.